# Lazy loading in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So for example I have a collection of `tasks` inside a document `my-task` inside a collection of `comments`

`tasks/my-task/comments`

Is there a way to download the document along with the sub collection it holds

Adding something to the following to make some eager load of the sub collection?
`firebaseDb.collection('tasks').onSnapshot(snapshot => { }`

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late, but I ran into this question and I think it was [asked by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775364/firestore-how-can-i-get-the-collections-from-a-documentsnapshot). You can see in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775364/firestore-how-can-i-get-the-collections-from-a-documentsnapshot/46777405?sgp=2#46777405) (which was written by a `Firebase` engineer) that `Firebase` queries are shallow, which means that in order to get a sub-collection you'll have to make a new request to the server.