# Firestore - How Can I Get The Collections From a DocumentSnapshot?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have a `userSnapshot` which I have got using `get` operation:

```
DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot=task.getResult().getData();
```

I know that I'm able to get a `field` from a `documentSnapshot` like this (for example):

```
String userName = userSnapshot.getString("name");
```

It just helps me with getting the values of the `fields`, but what if I want to get a `collection` under this `userSnapshot`? For example, its `friends_list` `collection` which contains `documents` of friends.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Queries in Cloud Firestore are shallow.  This means when you `get()` a document you do not download any of the data in subcollections.

If you want to get the data in the subcollections, you need to make a second request:

```
// Get the document
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

            // ...

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting document.", task.getException());
        }
    }
});

// Get a subcollection
docRef.collection("friends_list").get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting subcollection.", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```